# ive tried to implement multiple clients through threads, i am able to connect multiple clients if they are local, but accepts only 1 external connect

Tags: python, sockets, python-multithreading

the main premise of the problem is to build a first responders system of sorts, which pings location to a server when a collision occurs(collision is currently an event triggered when the key k is pressed)

```
import socket
import threading
i=0
def handle_client(client_socket, client_address):
    print(f"Accepted connection from {client_address[0]}:{client_address[1]}")
    resp = "connected".encode("utf-8")
    global i
    i=i+1
    id=f"{i}".encode("utf-8")
    client_socket.send(resp)
    client_socket.send(id)

    while True:
        req = client_socket.recv(1024)
        if not req:  # Handle empty request (client disconnects)
            break
        req = req.decode("utf-8")

        if req == "flag":
            accident_info = client_socket.recv(1024).decode("utf-8")
            print(f"Accident occurred: {accident_info}")
            resp = "close".encode("utf-8")
            client_socket.send(resp)
            break

        print(f"Received from {client_address[0]}:{client_address[1]}: {req}")
        resp = "accepted".encode("utf-8")
        client_socket.send(resp)

    client_socket.close()
    print(f"Connection with {client_address[0]}:{client_address[1]} closed")

def run_server():
    server_socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    server_ip = "127.0.0.1"
    port = 12345

    server_socket.bind(("", port))
    server_socket.listen(5)  # Increase the backlog to allow waiting connections
    print(f"Listening on {server_ip}:{port}")

    while True:
        client_socket, client_address = server_socket.accept()
        # Create a new thread to handle each client
        thread = threading.Thread(target=handle_client, args=(client_socket, client_address))
        thread.start()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    run_server()
```

Comment: I don't really understand what you are trying to achieve. Please don't just dump the code with some rudimentary and hard to understand error description, but instead show your actual tests using this code, describe what you expect to happen and show what happens instead - including full error messages, stack traces or whatever you get.

Answer (score 0):

To integrate collision detection into this system, you would need to modify the client-side code to send a "flag" message to the server when a collision occurs. This could be triggered by a key press or some other event in your client application.

For example, in the client code, you might add something like this:

```
if key_pressed == 'k':
    client_socket.send("flag".encode("utf-8"))
    accident_info = "Accident location: <location details>"
    client_socket.send(accident_info.encode("utf-8"))
```